# ggmap qmplot() object '.all_aesthetics' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to replicate an example from ggmap tutorial. Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

`%notin%` <- function(lhs, rhs) !(lhs %in% rhs)

violent_crimes <- crime %>% 
  filter(
    offense %notin% c("auto theft", "theft", "burglary"),
    -95.39681 <= lon & lon <= -95.34188,
     29.73631 <= lat & lat <=  29.78400
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    offense = fct_drop(offense),
    offense = fct_relevel(offense, 
      c("robbery", "aggravated assault", "rape", "murder")
    )
  )


qmplot(lon, lat, data = violent_crimes, maptype = "toner-lite", color = I("red"))
```

All I get is an error that reads as follows:

```
Error in match(names(x), .all_aesthetics) : object '.all_aesthetics' not found
```

I'm using ggmap version 2.6.1

Comment: I ran this with `ggmap` v 2.7.900 and got no error. Can you update the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue I was experiencing was a result of a not-up-to-date version of `ggmap` package. As recommended by [camille](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455936/ggmap-qmplot-object-all-aesthetics-not-found?noredirect=1#comment89882016_51455936) I decided to update the `ggmap` package. It turns out that it can't be done with `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")` while `ggplot2` has been installed from GitHub. As pointed out in this [thread](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/65) I went for downgrading `ggplot2` to the version available at CRAN (3.0.0) and had no problems installing `ggmap` from GitHub.